# Parabola equation expressed after x

Tags: conic-sections

Sorry for the bad title, as English is not my main language. Let me explain better what I mean.

I have this equation of parabola: $y = x^2 + 4x $

What I want to do is get the $x$ in one side and express it in relation to $y$ so that the equation takes this form:

$x = g(y)$

How do I proceed doing that?

Comment: You could complete the square and then solve for $x$

Comment: add 4 on both sides and try to solve for x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add 4 on both sides

$y+4=x^2+4x+4$

$\implies  (y+4)=(x+2)^2$

$\implies  (x+2)=(y+4)^{1/2}$

$\implies  x=(y+4)^{1/2}-2$

Comment: Oh, it was that easy after all. Didn't think of completing the square. Thanks a lot!